# Docker - Cannot delete files inside container via script

Tags: docker, delete-file, postgresql-13

On this Postgres Docker image, I'm copying a couple of files over to configure the container.

(1) init.sh - copies to Docker entrypoint
(2) data.txt - containing sensitive information

At the end of init.sh I want to delete data.txt, but the file never gets deleted.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  postgres_test:
    container_name: postgres_13_3
    image: postgres_13_3
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: ./postgres
      dockerfile: postgres_13_test.dk
    environment:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'test'
```

postgres_13_test.dk

```
FROM postgres:13.3-alpine3.14

# copy files over
COPY ./data.txt /tmp/data.txt
RUN chmod 777 /tmp/data.txt
COPY ./init.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sh
```

init.sh

```
# ... do other things first

# then in the end, delete file
rm -rf /tmp/data.txt     # <-- file never gets deleted
```

What am I missing ?

**UPDATE**

Now rebuild the conatainer fesh w/ --no-cache, and now it shows this error message

```
postgres_13_3  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sh
postgres_13_3  | rm: can't remove '/tmp/data.txt': Operation not permitted
```

How can I prevent this error ?

Comment: Are you sure you have your entrypoint set up correctly and the script is actually executing?

Comment: @Elia yes, the script is executing. It is creating db users and tables, which are all there. I left that out in the example code.

Comment: I assume copying the file through the dockerfile is preformed by root user, but init.sh is ran by the postgress user and this is the reason you don't have the permissions deleting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you check its [docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/517c64f87e6661366b415df3f2273c76cea428b0/13/alpine/docker-entrypoint.sh#L292), you will find the script `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*` only be executed once when database setup at first time, this is why you later see your `init.sh` not executed.
- After you setup a new container, the script has chance to execute, but you see permission issue, this is because the `init.sh` will be executed with `postgres` user, not `root` user, see [this](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/517c64f87e6661366b415df3f2273c76cea428b0/13/alpine/docker-entrypoint.sh#L286):

  ```
  if [ "$(id -u)" = '0' ]; then
          # then restart script as postgres user
          exec su-exec postgres "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@"
  fi
  ```

  Additional, if you check the permission of `/tmp`, you could see its permission is:

  ```
  ls -alh /tmp
  total 8K
  drwxrwxrwt    1 root     root        4.0K Aug  7 15:16 .
  drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Aug  7 15:25 ..
  -rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           0 Aug  7 15:01 data.txt
  ```

  Here, `t` is `sticky bit` which means if user `postgres` and `root` not in same linux group, you won't be able to delete file although you still have `w` permission of `/tmp`. This is the reason you can't delete `data.txt` even you change permission to `777` for `data.txt`.

So, for you, the solution is to change the ownership of `data.txt` to `postgres` something with `chown` like next:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM postgres:13.3-alpine3.14

COPY ./data.txt /tmp/data.txt
RUN chmod 777 /tmp/data.txt
RUN chown postgres:postgres /tmp/data.txt
COPY ./init.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sh
```

**Or**, not copy `data.txt` to `/tmp`, just setup a new folder like `/tmp2`, change its permission to `777`, and copy `data.txt` to `/tmp2`.